# How to generate Permutation Linear Extension using Python

Tags: python, list, permutation

I want to reproduce the experiment from [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eilyas/papers/SolimanVLDBJ2010.pdf). The authors said that they used linear extension, the definition of linear extension from MathWorld is:

*A linear extension of a partially ordered set P is a permutation of the elements p_1, p_2, ... of P such that p_i<p_j implies i<j. For example, the linear extensions of the partially ordered set **((1,2),(3,4)) are 1234, 1324, 1342, 3124, 3142, and 3412**, all of which have 1 before 2 and 3 before 4.*

Based on the definition of linear extension, I found python code something like this

```
import itertools

groups = [(1,2),(3,4)]
groupdxs = [i for i, group in enumerate(groups) for j in range(len(group))]
old_combo = ()
for dx_combo in itertools.permutations(groupdxs):
    if dx_combo <= old_combo: # as simple filter
        continue
    old_combo = dx_combo
    iters = [iter(group) for group in groups]
    print([next(iters[i]) for i in dx_combo])
```

The result is exactly the same according to the definition of linear extension:
This is the result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

However, I have no idea how to implement this according to the paper:

1. The linear extension in the paper is based on descending order, the high score comes first.
2. It seems the linear extension in the paper is based on a dictionary instead of a tuple.

Let say I have a Pandas dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['a1', '10-11'], ['a2', '3-8'], ['a3', '4-6'],['a4','1-2'], ['a5','5-10']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B']) 
df
```

df:

```
     A   B
0   a1  10-11
1   a2  3-8
2   a3  4-6
3   a4  1-2
4   a5  5-10
```

My question is how to generate all permutation from `df` according to the paper? The example linear extension from the paper can be seen in the figure below:

[image]

The expected results would be like:

```
[a1, a5, a3, a2, a4]
[a1, a2, a5, a3, a4] 
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mirror the traversal of the graph by using a recursive generator function to produce the desired results:

Output on data from paper:

```
data = [['a1', '9'], ['a2', '5-8'], ['a3', '7'],['a4','0-10'], ['a5','4']]  
r = {a:list(map(int, b.split('-'))) for a, b in data}
vals = [(a, [[j, a] for j in range(b, b+1 if not x else x[0]+1)][::-1]) for a, (b, *x) in r.items()]
def get_combos(vals, c = []):
   v = [(i, [a, b]) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(vals) if a not in c]
   start = [a for i, (a, b) in v if all(b[0][0] > min([x for x, _ in k]) 
            for l, (j, k) in v if l != i)]
   if c:
      start = sorted(start, key=lambda x:r[x][-1], reverse=True)
   if not start:
      yield c
   else:
      yield from [i for b in start for i in get_combos(vals, c=c+[b])]

print(list(get_combos(vals)))
```

Result:

```
[['a1', 'a4', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5'], ['a1', 'a4', 'a3', 'a2', 'a5'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a3', 'a5'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5', 'a4'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a4', 'a2', 'a5'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a2', 'a5', 'a4'], ['a4', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5'], ['a4', 'a1', 'a3', 'a2', 'a5']]
```

Output on your data:

```
data = [['a1', '10-11'], ['a2', '3-8'], ['a3', '4-6'],['a4','1-2'], ['a5','5-10']] 
r = {a:list(map(int, b.split('-'))) for a, b in data}
vals = [(a, [[j, a] for j in range(b, b+1 if not x else x[0]+1)][::-1]) for a, (b, *x) in r.items()]
print(list(get_combos(vals)))
```

Result:

```
[['a1', 'a5', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], ['a1', 'a5', 'a3', 'a2', 'a4'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a5', 'a3', 'a4'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5', 'a4'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a5', 'a2', 'a4'], ['a1', 'a3', 'a2', 'a5', 'a4']]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ajax1234 I upvoted your answer, I don't know why someone gave you a downvote, maybe they just press the wrong button. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @rischan Glad to help!

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234 wait for a second, what if the value in the rage is float? I got this error, 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: @rischan You can round by using `int`: `range(int(b), int(b+1 if not x else x[0]+1))`